# How to fill in missing/NA values in raster with terra package?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a DEM raster that has small holes (i.e. NAs) in it that I would like to fill, without altering any of the non-NA values. After reading about a [solution suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278476/filling-na-gaps-in-raster-with-r) for the raster package, I tried using terra's focal function with the following arguments: `focal(m, w=9, fun=mean, NAonly=T, na.rm=T)`. While this did mostly fill the hole, it appears that the surrounding data was slightly "smoothed" suggesting that the function did not limit itself to only filling NA values (the images below show before and after images).

Does the `NAonly=T` argument still apply in terra as it did in raster? Or is there a better way to fill holes without chaning non-NAs in terra?

DEM prior to applying focal function (yes, the hole was partially filled already)
[image: DEM prior to applying focal function]

DEM after applying focal function. Note the overall smoother appearance of the DEM.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like argument for terra is `na.policy="only"` rather than `NAonly=TRUE` used in raster. So `focal(m, w=9, fun=mean, na.policy="only", na.rm=T)` solves this issue. It's slight "boxier" than some other methods that I have used but otherwise it did the job.

I have also noticed that the output raster is moved by ~1/2 the focal window width but I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803441/why-is-terras-focal-function-changing-raster-location) about solving that issue.

UPDATE:
As of 1.5.27 this bug has been fixed.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to apply focal only to certain cells? When I use focal the edges of my raster expand outside the original boundaries of the data,  for example at the interface between land and sea