# Why is terra's focal function changing raster location?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am using the focal function in the terra package to fill holes in a DEM raster. However, after running `focal(m, w=19, fun=mean, na.policy="only", na.rm=TRUE)` my DEM is moved ~11cm relative to it's original position (see images below). This problem does not occur when I simply read in the raster using `rast()` and then write it using `writeRaster()`, but it happens when I use `focal()` regardless of whether I save the output using `writeRaster()` or using the `filename =`  argument within `focal()`.

I have also noticed that the larger the window size used, the greater the movement of the output raster. A window size of 9 produced ~5cm error. Raster pixels are ~1.2cm in size so `focal()` appears to be causing a movement of ~1/2 the width of the window used. As far as I can tell the movement is straight up/north.

Any idea why this might be occuring and how it could be avoided?

This the correctly aligned raster:

[image]

And this is after running focal (w = 19):

[image]

Comment: Was there a change in `origin()` in before/after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug that, I believe, has been fixed in the development version of `terra` available at https://github.com/rspatial/terra (and that is also the best place to report bugs). Can you please try it?

Comment: when I run `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")` in R, I am getting this error: `configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’`. I seem to remember having this gdal-config issue in the past but I can't remember how to solve it. I'm on a Mac using Monterey 12.3.

Comment: R shows I have `"GDAL 3.2.3, released 2021/04/27"` while Terminal shows `GDAL 3.4.2, released 2022/03/08`. Not sure if this difference is the problem but I am having trouble getting R to update rgdal. I get the same error: `configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.`.

Comment: I would love to test this out but I'm still unable to get the development version to install.

Comment: I managed to get the development version (1.5.27)  to install on a windows desktop using `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`. It does appear the bug is corrected. Still not sure how to fix the gdal-config issue.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and sorry about the mac-install-trouble. Having two versions of GDAL installed is a common problem. There is plenty of discussion about this in various places, especially as it related to installing `sf`.